# Communicate between helper app and main app in sandbox

Tags: macos, cocoa, helper

I have a status bar application from which I can launch a helper application for preferences. All preferences are stored in `NSUserDefaults` in the helper app and are read using `addSuiteNamed:` in the main app.

I would like to notify the main app when preferences are changed in the helper app. What is the best way to do this?

I have tried using `NSDistributedNotificationCenter` but this is too slow and not very reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RMSharedPreferences](https://github.com/realmacsoftware/RMSharedPreferences) by Realmac Software seems to be what I was looking for. It allows communicating between multiple apps and it is very easy to setup and seems to be way more reliable than NSDistributedNotificationCenter.